# How to manage reviewers list using gitPython?

Tags: python-3.x, gerrit

This code uploads the Gerrit review and adds `"othername"` as reviewer, and sets committer as `"My Name"` as expected.

But its also adding `"My Name"` to reviewer list, I need to add only "othername" in reviewer list, author or commiter should not be added into reviewers list, is there a way?

```
from git import Repo, Actor
author = Actor("My Name", "myemail@adomain.com")
committer = author
commit_msg = "test reviewers"
repo = Repo('/tmp/tree/path')
reviewers=['othername']
index = repo.index
_file="test/file.txt"
index.add([_file])
index.commit(commit_msg, author=author, committer=committer)
run(["git", "push", "origin", "HEAD:refs/for/master"],cwd='/tmp/tree/path', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Comment: GitPython doesn't know anything about Gerrit. It's unlikely you'll be able to solve this without using some Gerrit-specific code.  Also, the code in your question doesn't appear to do anything with the `reviewers` variable.

Comment: (just completing to @larsks's comments) - The Review is a Gerrit concept, not a Git concept (think of Gerrit as a social platform on top of Git). Thus, you would need Gerrit client to be able to update Gerrit concepts.